# Trying to Create a BigQuery Dataset Transfer config from Project A to Project B in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a Service Account in Project A `admin@proj1.iam.gserviceaccount.com` this is a Project Owner Throughout my organization, so we use this to create resources in different projects using our Automation.

I am Trying to Create a `Google Big query Data Transfer Config` via Terraform in `Project B` using the Service account mentioned above from `Project A`.
And its giving me this error

```
Error creating Config: googleapi: Error 400: P4 service account needs iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken permission. Running the following command may resolve this error: gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding Admin@projectA.iam.gserviceaccount.com --member='serviceAccount:service-<Project_B_ID>@gcp-sa-bigquerydatatransfer.iam.gserviceaccount.com' --role='roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator'
```

I tried running the above in `ProjectB` where the data set would be created, and it gave me a error the `admin@proj1.iam.gserviceaccount.com` does not exist.
I have not tried it(not allowed to run CLI cmd )in `ProjectA` plus everything is Managed via Terraform,  is there a way around to resolve this without needing to run this manually.

Or any other form to resolve this issue ?

FYI: This is only about resource creation, the data set and its transfer are gonna be local to project B only

Comment: You can set that permission in Terraform, you haven't to run it manually. Be sure to have activated the API before and it should work.

Comment: If this answer helped you, you can upvote or accept the answer. This can help future users who are having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the user `“admin@proj1.iam.gserviceaccount.com”` to project B and assign the role `“roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator”`.More information [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/add-iam-policy-binding).

You can use this example code with terminal

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding Admin@projectA.iam.gserviceaccount.com --member='serviceAccount:service-<Project_B_ID>@gcp-sa-bigquerydatatransfer.iam.gserviceaccount.com' --role='roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator'
```

Or you can use the IAM console and assign this role [roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#bigquerydatatransfer.serviceAgent) to the user `admin@proj1.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.

[image]